# How to unpublish my new site while working on it?

Tags: login

Started a new site and will be working on it for several days before I want it published. I don't want my customers to see a site half done...ugh.

Comment: Why don't you just develop the site off line on your local computer. This way you have much better and faster control. I personally use XAMMP with windows on my computer. The big advantage also is, if you crash your site, you can just edit the affected file in second, no need to ftp files etc etc

Answer (score 1):

If you will want to do something by you self than you will have to create a custom html or php file a redirect your site to it, this can be done by using `template_include`, you will have do to something like:

```
function coming_soon_page( $template ) {

  if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $cs_template = locate_template( array( 'path/to-your/comingsoon-page.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $cs_template ) {
        return $cs_template ;
    }
  }

  return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'coming_soon_page', 99 );
```

You will have to put it on your theme `functions.php` and until you let it there the site will redirect all users not logged in to that file.

And if you will want to have some countdown function then take a look at: [EASY COUNTDOWN](http://trulycode.com/bytes/easy-countdown-to-date-with-javascript-jquery/)

But if you can't do it by your self then try using any plugin like: [Ultimate Coming Soon Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/)